# Constantly active window. Winium. Automated GUI tests

Tags: java, selenium, user-interface, jenkins, automated-tests

A constantly active window. I neeed an emulation of that a real person is looking at the screen.
I have to write automated tests for windows application, so I choose a Winium(https://github.com/2gis/Winium).
But I have a 1 problem. All this tests running on virtual machine and i also start them from jenkins, but they will work only if I connect by RDP to virtual machine and maximize window.
If I just connect by RDP, but minimize window, all tests gonna fail.

So can you help me, and say, are exists some kind of programs which emulate "human presence"? Also glade to hear about you expreience in Automated GUI and what of programm you're using.

Comment: Try with the official driver for windows: https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver

Comment: @FlorentB., sory for question, but - winappdriver - work the same way and i can write autotests for windows app?
+
The programm that i testing  wrote on Java. Hope that's will not have some iisue abot that?

Comment: @FlorentB. WinAppDriver - can i write test on Java, or only on C# ?

Answer (score 0):

As a successful workaround, I've written a Visual Basic script that simulates continuous key presses on NumLock. This keeps my Remote Desktop session alive, even with the window minimized. My Winium scripts run fine within a grid (Hub-Node) setup (both hub and node are VMs) and the simulated keypresses don't interfere with testing.